# Android complex layout with scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view, android-scrollview

I got it from designer. Some unnecessary information has removed. Would anybody suggest me how can achieve this design exactly. From the aspect of android layout design here we need a **VerticalScrollView/ListView** and there are many **HorizontalScrollView** inside of that. I know ListView can't be put inside of ScrollView and vise versa. So we have to use only HScrollview inside of VScrollview. **For me the most toughest thing in this layout is the arrow (marked as red color in).** I would be grateful if anybody help me for any aspect of this layout.

Thanks in advance.

[image: HorizontalScrollView inside of VerticalScrollView]

Comment: From this image i cannot guess the workflow. where exactly the first(lady) image resides at(within a listview or in a gridview or simple layout)?

Comment: First image is not a part of any scrollview. You can discard this. I marked the Vertical scroll view and Horizontal Scroll view.

Comment: You could try ListPopupWindow http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html or PopupWindow with scrollview content http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: @mahbub.kuet Is the arrow indicating the lady dynamic?

Comment: @ParthaChakraborty Please see updated layout image.

Comment: Use a `ListView` with a header instead of `ScrollView`. As for the arrow, you can create it using a nine patch drawable. If it is meant to overlap to the upper row, then you will need to include it in there.

Comment: I've seen this before in a web browser where edge swipe takes to next previous tabbed view and swipe in middle moves a zoomed in web view.

Comment: @Ravi I understood what you said but you see the left vertical text "Text Here". That will create a problem in what you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but might give you an idea .

For the arrow part add arrow for the view and keep it visible only for the desired ones while keeping other hidden i.e at a time only one arrow will be vissible and other will be hidden.You can do this via code.

Remember the arrows are not at the center always ,you have to adjust it based on the location of the tile..

Answer (score 0):

I would use a listview with horizontal scrollview as list item.
In the Scrollview, I would populate each of those person info such that:
1st item gets that static arrow on top but others will just be a view. 
For the selected User profile the arrow is placed at the bottom. 
Listview with the divider should give you the desired look.

Note: Horizontal scrolling might be tricky if you have a hamburger menu that is suppose to open side swype.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, create a vertical scrollview and add [HorizontalListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView) enclosed in a LinearLayout, to scroll items from left to right.  The vertical scrollview will ensure you can scroll up and down through a series of horizontal lists.

e.g.:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout...
       <HListView....
         ....
      />
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use ListView and put HorizontalListView/ViewPager as one item into it. HorizontalListView can be found at Github or somewhere else.

About the arrow, you can try this way. Don't imply the orange line as one view. Each item hold one piece of the straight line, and the selected item use the "line with arrow" instead of straight line. It means, each item hold one avatar, TextViews and one ImageView as bottom orange line.

Answer (score 0):

As we know we can **customize** listviews. As others have already suggested about how to attain the main layout using different possible views I will stick to the **arrow** part of it.Consider you have a customized horizontal ListView which has a an ImageView,a TextView(as shown in the diagram), etc.. You can also add a colored rectangle/line/shape to it (Below the Textview, because you can customize the appearance of your listview).So each list item will have it so it will look continuous.Now comes the main point:

1)Suppose when user clicks on this list item, you call onItemClickListener() and you change the shape of the rectangle/line in that specific Item which will give the appearance that you want.

2)If you want that some thing should happen when the list item is pressed, I would suggest to use Onlongpressed() so that when user taps and hold the list item you can do the necessary action then.

Comment: @mahbub Hope it helps. Do tell me if i missed out on something or if you have any doubt.